# animated voronoi background

Tags: vector, svg, jquery-animate, voronoi

I really like the effect of the water in the video game Monument Valley.
I think this is an SVG voronoi diagram, but I am not sure how to get it to animate naturally like water, and how to get it to reflect colors when it is at certain angles.

Note also that Snap.svg has a similar patter in a demo at http://snapsvg.io/demos/#display

I'd like to find a tutorial on how to create this as a background for a welcome screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a delaunay triangulation of 3d points. Here is an example for 2d http://sandropaganotti.com/2014/05/04/how-to-render-a-dynamic-animated-delaunay-triangulation/.

Comment: @JurgenMantzke:If my answer is helpful please consi,der to accept and/or upvote it!

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get to look at it until now. I found a JavaScript library called Flat Surface Shader which did the same thing.

Comment: @JurgenMantzke:If my answer is helpful please consider to accept it!